# Combine multiple images on a webpage and change them individually by clicking buttons

Tags: php, jquery, html, image, png

I'm an ammature when it comes to webdesigning, I sort of ctrl+c > ctrl+v all of the time trying to learn.
At the moment I'm making a webapplication for selecting cushions on a couch.
I created a page where you can click on a color to see the cushions in that specific color, but I would like to change the color of the base of the couch also.

In short: I would like to place 2 png images on top of each other and be able to change them individually by clicking on colors.

My code for now:

```
<body>
<div id="page">
    <div id="gallery">
        <div id="panel"><img id="largeImage" src="images/image_01_large.png"/>

            <div id="thumbs">
                <img src="images/image_01_thumb.png" alt="Lime Green"/>
                <img src="images/image_02_thumb.png" alt="Burgundy"/>
                <img src="images/image_03_thumb.png" alt="Cobalt Blue"/>
            </div>
            <script>
                $('#thumbs').delegate('img', 'click', function () {
                $('#largeImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
                $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
            });
```

Comment: at least please put your code here!!

Comment: in short this is more javascript question than php one ;)

Comment: you tried anywhere or just directly ask question

Comment: it is like to get ready made code from other!!!

Comment: This boils down to `element.style.display = "";` to show, and to hide `element.style.display = "none";`

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for a ready made code, just trying to learn. I've looked on the internet and found information about layering images by using the same Z axes. I couldn't find how to adjust both layers separately.

Comment: The code I have so far (without the layering): 

<body> 
<div id="page">
<div id="gallery">
 <div id="panel">
  <img id="largeImage" src="images/image_01_large.png" />
 

 <div id="thumbs">
        <img src="images/image_01_thumb.png" alt="Lime Green" /> 
        <img src="images/image_02_thumb.png" alt="Burgundy" />
        <img src="images/image_03_thumb.png" alt="Cobalt Blue" />

    </div>
<script>
$('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){
 $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
 $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
});

Comment: This really is better suited for somewhere like [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [WebApps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I would suggest putting some time into learning javascript instead of trying to piecemeal together things. There are lots of good tutorials out there and you should be able to handle this problem fairly quickly after some good tutorials.  

http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript-combined

Comment: Thank you for the link Jeremy, I will definitely put time and effort in exploring the online course.